# Visual Studio 2017 - User Macro for Build Event

Tags: visual-studio, macros, post-build-event, build-events

I cannot find any option to add custom Macros (for Build Events).
I am in a .Net environment and its about Visual Studio 2017.

I want to define a "var" which can be **used both in the Build Events $(myVar) and in Code**. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pre-build event that generates a C# file (using `echo ... > file.cs`) that declares a class with a constant.

You would define the variable as an MSBuild variable in a tag in the project file.